# Is there a good program to download or online for plotting certain functions in 3d?

Tags: calculus, geometry, 3d, math-software

I am interested in a program that can plot me, without too much trouble shapes in 3d, when I type in the function. For example a elliptical paraboloid and an ellipse of the same time, so I can analyze the shape..

Comment: Have you tried the usual ones, Mathematica (or its online version Wolfram Alpha), Matlab...?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems - you can peruse this list and pick a free CAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [3D Calc Plotter](http://web.monroecc.edu/manila/webfiles/calcNSF/JavaCode/CalcPlot3D.htm)

You'll need a browser that can load legacy Javascript, like say Internet Explorer 10.  The link will not work in Chrome or the new Microsoft Edge browser. But it is very full featured. You can save the graphs to print in a 3d printer and a host of other options.